# How to use the rank function in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, dask, rank

How to use the pandas's `pd.rank()` function on dask dataframe.
Or is there any alternative inbuild function in dask to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this operation is not supported.  It is hard to do in parallel, and rarely fully needed.  You might instead collect the `nlargest` and then compute `pd.rank` on the computed pandas result?

Alternatively, if you're trying to compute rank across columns then you could use `map_partitions`

```
df.map_partitions(pd.rank, axis="columns")
```